# Running a MS-SQL Server Stored Procedure from MS Access?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-access, stored-procedures

I have an Access 2010 front-end to an SQL-Server 2008 database. I'd like to use the stored procedures already on the server via the front-end!

Is this even possible?

(Bit of a newb so go easy on me (-: )

Comment: Just realised this may be in the wrong place! Should I try Stack Overflow instead?

Comment: SO is probably a better place. The answer actually depends on the type of stored procedure, whether it returns records, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of connection do you have?  Does it let you pass T-SQL statements?  If so, you should be able to just EXEC the sprocs...  Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Access, only SQL Server.

Comment: ODBC, I believe!

Answer (score 1):

You can fire stored procedures using ADO. Below is a link to an article detailing exactly how to do it and also get the result back

http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/205120-get-stored-procedure-output-value-back-vba